# CEF Sharp - C# WPF published project won't run - throws error -Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.1316,

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

Program runs fine in VS 2019 but after publishing it wont run on any machine (that I have) even when installed on development machine.

It will however run on the development machine if you just go to the bin/release directory and run the executable from there. I am using CEF Sharp WPF ver. 88.2.9, have ensured that Visual C++ 2015 - 2019 is installed on target machines and as per CEF readme file all required and optional files are where they should be. Using NET 5.0.2. I have read other articles in SO related to this issue but solutions don't work in this case.  Not sure where to go from here. Any assistance would be appreciated. TY.

For those with much more experience than me, I include dumps from event viewer and Windows Error Report
to see if someone can glean what it is that is causing issue. Appears to be System.IO.FileNotFound related but that's as far as I can go with my knowledge.

**Event viewer dump:**

```
Log Name:      Application

Source:        Application Error

Date:          2021-03-09 11:32:59 AM

Event ID:      1000

Task Category: (100)

Level:         Error

Keywords:      Classic

User:          N/A

Computer:      Basement-Desktop

Description:Faulting application

name: Party.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xdbc3b417

Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.1316, time stamp: 0x7a6bfa05

Exception code: 0xe0434352

Fault offset: 0x001146d2

Faulting process id: 0x22a8

Faulting application start time: 0x01d71501ddc1ee2b

Faulting application path:C:\Users\echo_\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\RORBVQN7.01M\5TCJ3Z68.6JQ\carr..tion_8d98cc0aca4d0797_0001.0000_9e5bcffa72a3ecf2\Party.exe

Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll

Report Id: c6a499a9-2d2d-401b-aab3-a49c96fc7cd9

Faulting package full name: 

Faulting package-relative application ID:
 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-03-09T16:32:59.586238500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>69521</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Basement-Desktop</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Party.exe</Data>
    <Data>1.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>dbc3b417</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>10.0.18362.1316</Data>
    <Data>7a6bfa05</Data>
    <Data>e0434352</Data>
    <Data>001146d2</Data>
    <Data>22a8</Data>
    <Data>01d71501ddc1ee2b</Data>
    <Data>C:\Users\echo_\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\RORBVQN7.01M\5TCJ3Z68.6JQ\carr..tion_8d98cc0aca4d0797_0001.0000_9e5bcffa72a3ecf2\Party.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>c6a499a9-2d2d-401b-aab3-a49c96fc7cd9</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          2021-03-09 11:32:59 AM
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Basement-Desktop
Description:
Application: Carrie Oakey Party.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at CefSharp.Cef.get_IsInitialized()
   at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.NoInliningConstructor()
   at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser..ctor()

Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at Carrie_Oakey_Party.App.Main()


Event Xml:

    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
      <System>
        <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
        <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-03-09T16:32:59.421986200Z" />
        <EventRecordID>69520</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>Basement-Desktop</Computer>
        <Security />
      </System>
      <EventData>
        <Data>Application:Party.exe

Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at CefSharp.Cef.get_IsInitialized()
   at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.NoInliningConstructor()
   at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser..ctor()

Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.&lt;.ctor&gt;b__1_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at Party.App.Main()

</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**Here is output from windows error report:**

```
Version=1

EventType=CLR20r3

EventTime=132599499464911606

ReportType=2

Consent=1

UploadTime=132599499467496607

ReportStatus=268435456

ReportIdentifier=dbb94976-5f44-4b4f-97cf-9a29c9b534a1

IntegratorReportIdentifier=d4f91820-a97c-4882-ad29-81da288634fe

Wow64Host=34404

NsAppName= Party.exe

OriginalFilename= Party.exe

AppSessionGuid=00005ff4-0001-003b-61c1-d7ce8a16d701

TargetAppId=W:0006c19ab970b00ae815db6e7557e6447faa00000000!000046b23e5c393e9aa67e6e4dbf71d19c87eeb0e075!Party.exe

TargetAppVer=2069//07//26:19:52:22!3acc9!Party.exe

BootId=4294967295

ServiceSplit=2454257848

TargetAsId=3261

IsFatal=1

EtwNonCollectReason=1

Response.BucketId=3a38bc3df19e783d6d112aff3eed093b

Response.BucketTable=5

Response.LegacyBucketId=2094502577464740155

Response.type=4

Sig[0].Name=Problem Signature 01

Sig[0].Value=Party.exe

Sig[1].Name=Problem Signature 02

Sig[1].Value=1.0.0.0

Sig[2].Name=Problem Signature 03

Sig[2].Value=bb488c76

Sig[3].Name=Problem Signature 04

Sig[3].Value=CefSharp.Wpf

Sig[4].Name=Problem Signature 05

Sig[4].Value=88.2.90.0

Sig[5].Name=Problem Signature 06

Sig[5].Value=604178c7

Sig[6].Name=Problem Signature 07

Sig[6].Value=fb

Sig[7].Name=Problem Signature 08

Sig[7].Value=6

Sig[8].Name=Problem Signature 09

Sig[8].Value=System.IO.FileNotFoundException

DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version

DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.18363.2.0.0.768.101

DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID

DynamicSig[2].Value=4105

DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1

DynamicSig[22].Value=322b

DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2

DynamicSig[23].Value=322b30e1f6f6337d2b72a6e469d24f66

DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3

DynamicSig[24].Value=a735

DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4

DynamicSig[25].Value=a735f34ff5a8ea37f5643cfd852ddb5a

UI[2]=C:\Users\echo_\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\VB6J5Z9W.5MO\6MHKM2OX.7QG\carr..tion_8d98cc0aca4d0797_0001.0000_354ea773b12bcca0\Party.exe

LoadedModule[0]=C:\Users\echo_\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\VB6J5Z9W.5MO\6MHKM2OX.7QG\carr..tion_8d98cc0aca4d0797_0001.0000_354ea773b12bcca0\Party.exe

LoadedModule[1]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[20]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ucrtbase_clr0400.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\ed4777cae83e1fc9087ac3dc82cf23ab\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dfshim.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\UMPDC.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\cryptsp.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
LoadedModule[40]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\76c2318d9c3680627b8a4a680bb84f48\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Core\8e03f9afd831af61f8413ed5a6b394cd\System.Core.ni.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\WindowsBase\7d71cc384cc5d5c38b57e6118937b4b1\WindowsBase.ni.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\PresentationCore\1696a67907e15cf05e5c627014d48d2f\PresentationCore.ni.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Presentatio5ae0f00f#\8b222f01bcfb013b8772a3029f974ff1\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xaml\9cc89c6247c50d6cb0b808f64715e3fa\System.Xaml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwrite.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationNative_v0400.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Configuration\0230074871fa66a53c18cf61aa79cb38\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xml\dc6e982e28f321870f322f1b3af2d83e\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
OsInfo[0].Key=vermaj
OsInfo[0].Value=10
OsInfo[1].Key=vermin
OsInfo[1].Value=0
OsInfo[2].Key=verbld
OsInfo[2].Value=18363
OsInfo[3].Key=ubr
OsInfo[3].Value=1379
OsInfo[4].Key=versp
OsInfo[4].Value=0
OsInfo[5].Key=arch
OsInfo[5].Value=9
OsInfo[6].Key=lcid
OsInfo[6].Value=1033
OsInfo[7].Key=geoid
OsInfo[7].Value=39
OsInfo[8].Key=sku
OsInfo[8].Value=101
OsInfo[9].Key=domain
OsInfo[9].Value=0
OsInfo[10].Key=prodsuite
OsInfo[10].Value=768
OsInfo[11].Key=ntprodtype
OsInfo[11].Value=1
OsInfo[12].Key=platid
OsInfo[12].Value=10
OsInfo[13].Key=sr
OsInfo[13].Value=0
OsInfo[14].Key=tmsi
OsInfo[14].Value=544726
OsInfo[15].Key=osinsty
OsInfo[15].Value=1
OsInfo[16].Key=iever
OsInfo[16].Value=11.1198.18362.0-11.0.220
OsInfo[17].Key=portos
OsInfo[17].Value=0
OsInfo[18].Key=ram
OsInfo[18].Value=16251
OsInfo[19].Key=svolsz
OsInfo[19].Value=118
OsInfo[20].Key=wimbt
OsInfo[20].Value=0
OsInfo[21].Key=blddt
OsInfo[21].Value=190318
OsInfo[22].Key=bldtm
OsInfo[22].Value=1202
OsInfo[23].Key=bldbrch
OsInfo[23].Value=19h1_release
OsInfo[24].Key=bldchk
OsInfo[24].Value=0
OsInfo[25].Key=wpvermaj
OsInfo[25].Value=0
OsInfo[26].Key=wpvermin
OsInfo[26].Value=0
OsInfo[27].Key=wpbuildmaj
OsInfo[27].Value=0
OsInfo[28].Key=wpbuildmin
OsInfo[28].Value=0
OsInfo[29].Key=osver
OsInfo[29].Value=10.0.18362.1379.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
OsInfo[30].Key=buildflightid
OsInfo[30].Value=E9D7DCF3-926E-471A-8D35-C0D4EA197451.1
OsInfo[31].Key=edition
OsInfo[31].Value=Core
OsInfo[32].Key=ring
OsInfo[32].Value=Retail
OsInfo[33].Key=expid
OsInfo[33].Value=RS:5789
OsInfo[34].Key=containerid
OsInfo[35].Key=containertype
OsInfo[36].Key=edu
OsInfo[36].Value=0
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=CLR20r3
AppName=Party
AppPath=C:\Users\echo_\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\VB6J5Z9W.5MO\6MHKM2OX.7QG\carr..tion_8d98cc0aca4d0797_0001.0000_354ea773b12bcca0\Party.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=4A25B4A8AE2E047E9A4AE0367F5D6048
MetadataHash=498109517
```

Comment: The same version of Net is required on both the build and the deploy machines.  If they are not the same you  must publish the application and install with the setup.exe folder like any commercial software.  The setup resolves difference in the Windows dlls that Net uses.

Comment: Are you using the CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore package or the older CefSharp.Wpf package? What options did you publish with?

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for taking the time to answer! If I run the published setup.exe on the build machine and then launch the program  - it fails with same error.

Comment: @amaitland I appreciate your response. Not sure what you mean by 'older' but I used CefSharp.Wpf . Options - included application files originally marked as 'exclude', .NET Runtime 5.0.3 (x64) & .NET Desktop Runtime 5.0.3(x64) as well as default items there.

Comment: The https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore/ package is designed to be used with .Net Core 3.1 and .Net 5.0 as detailed in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3284 the older CefSharp.Wpf package is actually targeting. Net 4.5.2.

Comment: You should be using Net 4.7.2 if you plan to target both Core and Net.  4.7.2 is supppose to fix all the targeting issues.

Comment: If you are targeting .Net 5 use the https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore/ package.

Comment: @amaitland  I redid the program using the .NETCore package. Published it in VS 2019 and I got this error thrown: "Description: A .NET Core application failed.
Message: Error: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (kR0Ke.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'CefSharp.Common.NETCore', version: '89.0.170'
    path: 'runtimes/win-x64/native/CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe' "
The deps.json file showed the location for the subprocess.exe  but it wasn't there. I placed the .exe in the runtimes folder and now it works. Do you know why it wouldn't get placed correctly?

Comment: Please read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3407 depending on your publish settings we won't include the browsersubprocess executable, it shouldn't be included in the deps.json in those scenarios. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/89/NuGet/PackageReference/CefSharp.Common.NETCore.targets#L24 What publish settings did you use?

Comment: @amaitland Publish settings: Configuration - Release | x64, Target Framework - netcoreapp3.1, Deployment mode - Framework-dependent, Target runtime - Portable.

Comment: Please try changing target runtime to win-x64.

Comment: @amaitland unfortunately no change. Browsersubprocess.exe still needs to placed manually.

Comment: Testing with the settings at https://gist.github.com/amaitland/51002db8c7191d8ac818d754f73309a4 using https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample and the publish has the browsersubprocess as expected. Can you edit your original question and provide a copy of the xml in your FolderProfile.pubxml file. The CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe should only be excluded for single file publish builds.

Comment: @maitland I was using Click Once. I tried using Folder and it worked as you indicate. So something up with Click Once - I guess?